# New monitor in sleep mode and not displaying HDMI is active

Tags: windows-10, display, hdmi, displayport, hp-pavilion

I bought a new HP curved monitor v27cGSFHD. I have a HP desktop thats older that worked with my old monitor that was Dell. I connected my new monitor with a DVI to HDMI adapter.  Its says that the HDMI port is active but it doesn't display anything. Display port is inactive. It came on one time on the first day but hasn't since. I installed the driver for the monitor as the guide said to go to hp.com/support and do so. After that, still no success. Im beginning to think I should return it. I am running on Windows 10 version 22H2. I didn't think I needed to do anything else. Can you help? I can connect my old monitor back and it works fine.

Comment: Ask HP Support about it and return it if not satisfactory.

Comment: Im asking here because i did that first and got no help

Comment: Connect it to a different device. Go buy a RPi and try with it.

Comment: Thanks.  My problem has been resolved.

Comment: If it has been resolved, you are requested to detail _how_.

Comment: I replaced the monitor